Strikethrough text only when printing to PDF via VBA (inconsistent issue)
I have a spreadsheet that prints to PDF with the click of a button. The relevant VBA code is shown below. This print to PDF code has functioned flawlessly for years, but out of nowhere, people are starting to get strikethrough text on their PDFs. This issue does not occur with everyone (it doesn't occur for me). The strikethrough text also doesn't show up in the spreadsheet itself, just the PDF.
Range(printrange).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=filepath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

I made sure that everyone that has the issue is printing using the same PDF printer as me, but that hasn't resolved the problem. Also, we discovered that this issue doesn't occur when they manually print, only when they use the button to print to PDF.
I am open to any suggestions. Thank you for your help!
What I see
What others see

ExportAsFixedFormat doesn't use a pdf printer, its like save as -> pdf. Does this problem also occur if the document is saved manual as a pdf?

Is there any conditional formatting on the cells in question ? See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-question-why-strikethrough-when-i-dont-want/7c404ee0-7ac4-41c2-a8ef-ce3099459456
Would you be able to provide a sample Excel ?

This issue doesn't occur when the document is manually saved as a PDF (i.e. by using File > Print)

The Excel sheet looks perfect on both my end (which it's always looked fine for me) and on the users' end (including the ones with issues). Looks exactly like the "What I see" image

File > Print and Range.ExportAsFixedFormat are very different under the hood. File > Print goes over the Printer/PDF Driver by rendering objects. The Export is internal Code that creates a PDF. Your issue sounds like a weird bug or another undiscovered condition. You could try posting your issue in MS Excel Forums.

Thank you Hakan and Shrotter! I think I may switch to the .PrintOut method (which is apparently used when you use File > Print) and see if that solves it for them :)

I swapped to the .PrintOut method and my coworker is still getting that strikethrough problem.

it's new feauture in excel, "Stale Value Formatting":
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/stale-value-formatting-4b5c63c3-5dc7-4e9b-8e24-88bed1987dbd
You can turn it off or recalculate worksheet before print.
Thanks to A.Mack from Microsoft forum, he found this.
